# Unknown issue in downloader application .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to make a simple download application that takes the links from a text file and desired filename for the downloaded file and then downloads it.
I've completed the code but when I run the application, nothing happens. There is no run time error and I cannot figure out the problem in my code or logic.

Here is the complete code:

```
Imports System.Net

Public Class Form1

' the file has filename,link. Each even number is a filename, and odd number is a link
' program loads it seperately into different array
' then download the file with and save with it's filename

Dim WithEvents WC As New WebClient

Private Sub backgroundDownloader_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles backgroundDownloader.DoWork
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("down.txt")
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim file As String
    Dim path = "downloads\"

    ' filenames will be the same amount as links and vise-versa
    ' that means filenames and links are exactly half the size of total lines of files
    Dim filenames(lines.Length / 2) As String
    Dim links(lines.Length / 2) As String

    ' store value in arrays
    While counter < lines.Length
        ' using modulus operator to test odd or even counter
        If counter Mod 2 = 0 Then
            filenames(counter) = lines(counter)
            counter += 1
        Else
            links(counter) = lines(counter)
            counter += 1
        End If
    End While
    counter = 0

    ' add path to each filename
    Dim temp As String
    For Each file In filenames
        temp = ""
        temp = path + file
        file = temp
    Next

    'start download
    While counter < links.Length
        WC.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(links(counter)), filenames(counter))
        counter += 1
    End While
End Sub

Private Sub WC_DownloadProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles WC.DownloadProgressChanged

    ' update progressbar status
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage

    ' change status when done status when download completes
    If progressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        lblStatus.Text = "Downloads Completed!"
        picStatus.Image = Image.FromFile("resources\images\done.png")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    backgroundDownloader.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
End Class
```

The following are the contents of down.txt (file storing the name and links):

```
first.bin
https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin
second.bin
https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin
third.bin
https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin
fourth.bin
https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin
```

The callstack doesn't show anything. It's all blank in the memory and variable window as show in the screenshot: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxCF8.png)

Any help or suggestion will he appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT(1) - Incremented the counter variable.

EDIT(2) - Used a temporary string for now to add path to filename

Comment: The first step of debugging is to put breakpoints and step through the code. If you were to do that, you would realize that you have an infinite loop, that is, `counter < lines.Length` is always true because you never increment `counter` in the first loop.

Comment: Also, `file = path & file` is not doing what you think it is doing to the items in `filenames`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It fixed part of the problems. Added: `counter += 1` in the infinite loop as per Ahmed. Also added a temporary string for adding path to filenames: `Dim temp As String : temp = path + file : file = temp`. Thanks for the help :)